# Removing highcharts.com credits link

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have just purchased [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), but the credits link still appears on my graphs which are quite prominent on my site and it distorts the chart view.

I assumed I would get an option, so how do I remove it?

Comment: Maybe you should contact the support.

Comment: I think for $160 you get support too!?

Comment: This is a good question with a very good simple answer. Some people just love closing questions without understanding anything

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/highcharts/2783/credits/9374/removing-highcharts-com-logo#t=20170316203422111424

Comment: I am voting to re-open this question. I don't see how it's off-topic (it also has 5 pending delete votes too). I know that the question was closed due to the OP's lack of effort, but this is the top Google result (which appears before the official documentation that I was looking for).

Comment: @JoshCrozier Just found this at the top of Google too. Any idea why it is being hammered with delete votes?

Comment: @Mitch - There are some people that naturally gravitate to casting delete votes on questions that are already closed. It is also likely that they don't even know what the library is. Often times they will just blindly vote to delete it when they come across it in [this review dashboard](http://stackoverflow.com/tools). Once a question like this has been deemed as off-topic, it is relatively hard to reverse it because reopen votes expire after a period of time.

Answer (score 644):

You can customise the credits, changing the URL, text, Position etc. All the info is documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits. To simply disable them altogether, use:

```
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
```

Comment: Yes. Highcharts is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: @MartinBrown They utilize "the honour system".

Comment: Hi, am using many `highcharts` functions with different `id`, is there any way to disable all credits in a single function" Thanks.

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain yes, you can add `credits: false` to `Highcharts.setOptions({})` and globally disable all credits

Comment: I am using HighCharts version 3.0.2. Have set up the Highcharts server locally for exporting the charts. When download as png/jpeg/pdf is selected from the top right corner of the chart , the Highcharts demo page is displayed. so how can stop that redirection can please help me

Comment: That's highchart is my first choice

Comment: @philfreo credits: false is not enough for the `@typings v3.0.0`. Even without the typings, its not as if it allows it, it just doesn't know what to do with the element value so it defaults it to `false`.

Comment: The code in this answer is the same as Ahmad's answer, and it looks like he posted the code solution first. imo your body text should have simply been a suggested improvement on Ahmad's answer.

Answer (score 248):

It's said [here](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13788) that you should be able to add the following to your chart config:

```
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
```

that will remove the "Highcharts.com" text from the bottom of the chart.

Comment: It looks like `credits: {
   'enabled': 'false'
  },` doesnt work (note the quotes). I am using that because that's what comes in from my Django app. But surprisingly, quotes dont matter for 3D options (i.e `'options3d':{'enabled':'true'}` works).

Comment: I could get around the above by sending the whole thing as string (credits = '{enabled: false}') in my django app (note the quotes) (in case others are also facing the same issue)

Comment: @Anupam, the reason `'true'` works, but not `'false'` is because both evaluate to `true`. =)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css.

```
.highcharts-credits {
display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
credits : null
```

also works to disable the credits