# Cannot Remove Credits (Link) in HighChart's PieChar

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I tried **enable:false**

but i cannot remove **highchart's** link from my chart (**pie**).
I got bit confused 
This is my Javascript code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   $(document).ready(function() {  

   var chart = {
   plotBackgroundColor: null,
   plotBorderWidth: null,
   plotShadow: false,
   credits: false ///<= HERE I TRIED IT LAST

   };
   var title = {
   text: ''   
   };      
   var tooltip = {
   pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f} Coupon(s)</b>'
   };
    var plotOptions = 
     {
     pie: {
     allowPointSelect: true,
     cursor: 'pointer',
     dataLabels: {
        enabled: false           
     },
     showInLegend: true,
     borderWidth: 0 
   },
    series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                halo: 
                    {
                      size: 0
                    }
                   }
                }
            },

  };

  var series= [{
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'Source',
  data: [
        <?php
        for($x=0; $x<sizeof($data); $x++)
        {
        echo $data[$x];
        echo ",";
        }
        ?>
        ]
 }];     

var json = {};   
json.chart = chart; 
json.title = title;     
json.tooltip = tooltip;  
json.series = series;
json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
$('#container').highcharts(json);  
});
</script>
```

I tried to put this code at multiple positions. But it is showing no result.
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using a licensed version, or are you using the free distribution?

Comment: Sorry I dont know this. I just included highcharts.js remotely. Didn't buy license either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing highcharts.com link credits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459224/removing-highcharts-com-link-credits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var license = {
             enabled: false
       };
```

then at bottom:

```
 json.credits = license;
```

[previously asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459224/removing-highcharts-com-link-credits)
If you are using the free version, you CAN remove the attribution link, but if you are using free code the honour system is there so at least you can leave a "hat tip" to the developers as a thank you for saving you time.

Comment: Can you just specify where to write this script

    **credits: {
      enabled: false
     },**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/credits/enabled-false/

Comment: Sorry but it didn't worked. My code is bit changed from that one in the demo. Can you please specify me in my code where should I use the script?

Comment: Worked like a charm sir :) Thanks