# remove Highchart.com link from the chart

Tags: jquery, symfony, highcharts

I use Highchart to designe a chart, but the problems that the link hightchart.com always available,

I user symfony and this is my code:

```
 $ob = new Highchart();
    // ID de l'élement de DOM que vous utilisez comme conteneur
    $ob->chart->renderTo('chart');

    $ob->chart->type('column');

    $ob->yAxis->title(array('text' => "nombre , sms, fax"));

    $ob->xAxis->title(array('text' => "mois"));
    $ob->xAxis->categories($horizontals);

    $ob->tooltip->headerFormat('<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>');
    $ob->tooltip->pointFormat('<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td><td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} </b></td></tr>');
    $ob->tooltip->footerFormat('</table>');
    $ob->tooltip->shared(true);
    $ob->tooltip->useHTML(true);
```

and this is the result

[image]

my question is how delete the tow elements 1 and 2

thanks for help

Comment: Yo remove #1 simply remove `exporting.js` file or set `$ob->exporting->enabled(false)` (or something similar). For #2 see answer below. Anyway, is there any online API for this symphony controller for Highcharts? I haven't found anything like that.

Answer (score 8):

Set this parameter when declaring Highchart object

```
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
```

Here is my example [jsfiddle.net/mxx8xpnL](http://jsfiddle.net/mxx8xpnL)

[Removing highcharts.com credits link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459224/removing-highcharts-com-link-credits)

Comment: I tried $ob->credits->enabled(false) but not working, I user the configuration in the symfony controller

Comment: Change this parameter when declaring highcart. 
Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/mxx8xpnL/

Answer (score 1):

for removing a link, you can use this :

```
 credits: {
    text: 'you text',
    href: false,
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ob->credits->enabled(false); // For credits
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This is the command to delete the credits. Here it's 2. He's using the Hightchart bundle for Symfony and don't have any JS because everything is on the controlle if you had this command, it remove the credit and it was a part of the question.